# php/javascript prevent page reload/refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my project i have a php page where i whant that in case of browser reload, or F5 the page redirect to another one.
I have insert this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.location.href = "../index.html";
}
</script>
```

If instead of window.location.href instruction i insert  an alert("test"); the code run, but with my code in case of refresh the page cannot redirect to index.html. Why?

Comment: You *can't* prevent this.

Comment: This is to prevent pages from preventing you from closing them.
Imagine what a pain it would be if browsers could keep redirecting you when you try to close a page.

Comment: And how is possible prevent the refresh on my php page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to redirect when user closes window or tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887606/how-to-redirect-when-user-closes-window-or-tab)

Comment: What is the problem on refresh? There is a form being posted?

Comment: my php page call a javascript function that call various ajax calls and if a user continues to make on the page refresh might consume all available bandwidth. 
Every time you do a refresh, the page re-run asynchronous calls

Comment: Then you should probably handle this on server side

Comment: So, maybe, you can cancel the ajax calls when the user goes out. The request will remains, but, you will avoid the response

Comment: in what way? with xmlHttp.abort();?

Comment: Cache the results from the ajax calls to prevent running them multiple times

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keypresses and handle events before a redirect. Although changing any default browser behavior may be considered [evil](http://lab.artlung.com/onunload-window-open-evil/) and more of an annoyance by your website users.

Here i have provided an example function to handle redirecting the user when they try to refresh the page. http://jsfiddle.net/dQEeW/

The heart of it and what handles the location change is this event binding.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function( event ){
        if( event !== undefined ) {
          if( (event.keyCode == 82 &&
                event.ctrlKey
               ) || (event.keyCode == 116) 
            ) {
              event.keyCode = 0;

              if(destination) window.location.href =  destination;

            return !destination; //false if destination was set true otherwise.
          }
        }
    });
```

The function was based on [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1400553/704765) but I have limited it to only handle F5 and expanded it a bit to handle CTRL+R. You can only limit the keyboard driven refreshes though.

Pulling from [yet another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6887615/704765) you may want to capture page unloads and return a string, to warn the users they are trying to do something it hasn't been designed to do.

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
      return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
  }
```

That should give you the opportunity to address the reason they want to leave and a chance for them to cancel it.